# Too much heap memory usage when reallocing

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, calloc, alloc

Valgrind says that 42 718 bytes were allocated, however, when I see how many times the reallocation procces is called, it's 3 or 6 times and variables `currentLength` and `currentLineLength` are 10 20 30 or 10 20 30 40 50 60, so the problem isn't in the looping.

```
char *textInFile = (char *) calloc(currentLength + 1, sizeof(char) * currentLength);
char *currentLine = (char *) calloc(currentLength + 1, sizeof(char) * currentLineLength);
char *ptr, *ptr2;
...
while ((textInFile[index] = getc(f)) != EOF) {
    if (index >= currentLength - 2) {
        currentLength += 10;
        ptr = (char *) realloc(textInFile, currentLength);
        textInFile = (char *) calloc(currentLength, sizeof(char) * currentLength);
        free(ptr);
    }
    if (index > 0) {
        if (textInFile[index - 1] == '\n') {
            goto End;
        }
    }
    if (textInFile[index] == '\n') {
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = previousIndex; i < index; i++) {
            if (k >= currentLineLength - 2) {
                printf("\nCurrent Length: %d\n", currentLineLength);
                currentLineLength += 10;
                ptr2 = (char *) realloc(currentLine, currentLineLength);
                currentLine = (char *) calloc(currentLineLength, sizeof(char) * currentLineLength);
                free(ptr2);
            }
            currentLine[k] = textInFile[i];
            k++;
        }
        previousIndex = index + 1;
    ...
    }
    End:
    index++;
}
free(textInFile);
free(currentLine);
...
```

`valgrind` output:

```
==4756== 
==4756== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4756==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4756==   total heap usage: 27 allocs, 27 frees, 42,718 bytes allocated
==4756== 
==4756== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4756==
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Valgrind shows more memory allocated than actually is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44271967/valgrind-shows-more-memory-allocated-than-actually-is)

Comment: [Don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/6699433)

Comment: @kaylum No, the answer is "probably". I need to know if it's in the code or valgrind.

Comment: @klutt This has nothing to do with it, or does it? I see no correlation, rather than just an advice.

Comment: Note, when `currentLength == 60`,  `calloc(currentLength + 1, sizeof(char) * currentLength);` is allocating 61*60 bytes.  I'd say a total of "42 718 bytes were allocated" looks about right.

Comment: @user3121023 I'll try that, but I need an answer to this since I'm trying to educate myself on the topic.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Wait, why? Size of char is 1, so it's 1 * 60, or isn't it? I may have misunderstood the calloc arguments.

Comment: `calloc(a, b)` allocated `a*b` bytes.  What did you think it did?

Comment: @tomashauser `calloc()` multiplies the two arguments to get the number of bytes to allocate. So that allocates `(currentlength + 1) * currentlength` bytes.

Comment: @tomashauser Just an advice

Comment: Recommend `textInFile = calloc(numberOfElements, sizeof *textInFile);`

Comment: What's the point of allocating `ptr` and then freeing it 2 lines later without using it?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I completely missed that. Answered.

Comment: @Barmar So I don't lose pointer to realloc.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Does that simultanously reallocate it? Don't I lose unfreed memory from mallocating?

Comment: tomashauser, `calloc()` and `malloc()` do not involve any re-allocation.  Use `realloc()` to re-allocate memory.  Still wondering about what did you think `calloc()` did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:**

```
void* calloc( size_t num, size_t size );
```

Calloc actually multiplies the num and size.